# Is the periodogram squared-magnitude DFT or squared-average DFT?

Tags: fft, power-spectral-density, periodic

How is the periodogram defined? I have been searching the internet a lot, and I find two different definitions:

- periodogram is the squared magnitude of the DFT
- periodogram is the squared average of the DFT

which one is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The periodogram is simply the squared magnitude of the DFT. Since the periodogram is a rather poor estimate of the power density spectrum of a random process there are methods which use averaging of periodograms to obtain better estimates of the power spectrum. Two such methods are [Welch's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_method) and [Bartlett's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartlett%27s_method).