# THD: estimation using periodogram or fft?

Tags: fft

I want to estimate the THD of a voltage signal (output from a frequency inverter). At the begining, I need to estimate the power of the signal at frequency domain. To doing so, I should use a periodogram or a FFT.

Matlab uses periodogram in his THD function. I know that are differences between FFT and periodogram, as shown in [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24780/power-spectral-density-vs-fft-bin-magnitude). But, wich method should I use? and why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just for answer the question, basically there is no difference at all. My problem was that I've compared a **modified** periodogram against a FFT. Modified periodogram does have a difference; but simple periodogram doesn't.

Comment: Might want to note the unit difference between |FFT| and |FFT|^2 (periodogram) in your answer, in case THD is computed using the harmonic power and not amplitude